# Calling a function from within the same var

Tags: javascript, function

I'm not sure if I have my syntax correct but for some reason I can't seem to call my function, my code is set up in the following way;

```
var MyMethod =
{
    MyFunction1: function(myData)
    {
        /// ...
        MyFunction2: ([myData]);
        return "YES";
    },

    MyFunction2: function(data)
    {
        // ...
        return 'YES';
    },
};
```

Is this the correct way to call the function? Function1 executes properly, but the I can't get the second function to execute with that call. I've tried just having it as `MyFunction2(myData)` etc as well but no luck either.

I have also thought that because my function is setup within the var, that I put function1 underneath function2 but that didn't work either.

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: opening braces `{` is missing

Comment: Thanks - I had this in my code but missed adding it in when typing up the question

Comment: @BASmith A little hint for future SO questions; **ALWAYS** paste code in

Comment: Yeah it was actually a copy and paste, but the MyMethod variable was much larger with more functions - when I was editing the other functions out to help with simplifying my question, I must have accidentally got rid of the bracket :-(

Answer (score 3):

```
var MyMethod = {
    MyFunction1: function(myData) {
        MyMethod.MyFunction2([myData]);
        return 'YES';
    },
    MyFunction2: function(data) {
        // whatever ...
        return 'YES';
    }
};
```

You can potentially also use `this.MyFunction2([myData])` however, execution of `MyFunction1` cannot be guaranteed to be using `MyMethod` as `this`, especially if you are using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
var MyMethod ={
MyFunction1: function(myData)
    {
        /// ...
       return  this.MyFunction2([myData]);
    },

MyFunction2: function(data)
    {
        // ...
        return data;
    },
};
var res = MyMethod.MyFunction1('a');
alert(res);
```

Comment: `this` refers to the head object (`MyMethod`). So this is correct.

Comment: @chovy not necessarily, eg `MyMethod.MyFunction1.call({}, someData)`

Comment: `var res =MyMethod.MyFunction1.call(MyMethod, 'a')` this will again work

Comment: @ArunKillu The point is, you cannot guarantee that the object referred to by `this` in `MyFunction1` will be `MyMethod`. Anything that makes use of this code may call `MyMethod.MyFunction1` with any `this` context it wants

Answer (score 1):

The method is not global, it's a member of the object, so you need to use `this` to access it, and the colon is not part of the identifier:

```
this.MyFunction2([myData]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var MyMethod = {

    MyFunction1: function (myData) {
        /// ...
       return  this.MyFunction2([myData]);

    },

    MyFunction2: function (data) {
        // ...
       return data;
    },
};
```

- here you have an object `Mymethod`,which has `Myfunction1` as its
  property and the `function` you assigned it as its value.
- So whenevr you want to access some value of an property,It should
  always be in the below manner:

`MyObject.Property`//similar to `Mymethod.MyFunction2(param)`

Before knowing the syntax ,I think you should know what is the meaning of object,property and method is:

**Object**:An object is a thing that has properties. Properties have names and values. The names are always strings (although we can write them without quotes most of the time), and the values can be anything JavaScript supports: Numbers, strings, booleans, null, undefined, or references to objects.

**property**: is simply a variable belonging to an object. A variable by itself is not a property.
Properties and variables can hold any kind of data.

**method**:When a property holds a function it's called a **method.**

Simplest way to understand is by example:

```
var a = {
    b: function () {some code}
    };

    a //is an object
    b //is property of a     aka b is a method since it holds a function as its value.
    function () { //some code}//is property value aka value of b.
```

Comment: BASmith:updated my answer..have a look,i think you are not clear about methods,objects,properties..